# Why aren't states with 3 basis vectors considered entanglements in two qubit system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

I am going to take out normalization factors for simplicity.
$$|00⟩+|11⟩$$
$$|00⟩−|11⟩$$
$$|10⟩+|01⟩$$
$$|10⟩−|01⟩$$
I can see why these states are entangled but I don't see why the following states are not considered entangled:
$$|00⟩+|10⟩+|11⟩$$
$$|00⟩+|01⟩+|11⟩$$
$$|10⟩+|01⟩+|00⟩$$
$$|10⟩+|01⟩+|11⟩$$

Comment: They are entangled.

Comment: Oh lol. Noone mentions these states when talking about entanglement so wasn’t sure why.

Comment: Remember normalisation. I think here you will find the solution you are looking for: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/how-do-i-show-that-a-two-qubit-state-is-an-entangled-state#:~:text=A%20more%20straightforward%20way%20to,Otherwise%20it%20is%20entangled.

Comment: So because $Tr(\rho^2) \neq 1$ , these states are entangled?